# JQgrid want an ALL option on the navigator

Tags: jqgrid, navigator

I am working on jqGrid.I had a problem in the navigator rowList.
my data to this field is like this rowList:['25','50','75','-1'].
I am using -1 to display all the records.In  the row list,i wish to use "All" instead of "-1" to display all the records is their any possibility to do this.

Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Phani Kumar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no `All` value as `rowNum` and in the `rowList` array. You should also not use `-1` (see documentation about [rowNum](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:options) for example) or other negative values. The value `-1` was allowed in some cases in the old releases of jqGrid, but it is no more supported in last releases. The value like 1000, 10000 are good enough depend on your requirements.

Having some realistic restrictions in the number of displayed rows is a good idea **independent on the jqGrid support**. No real user are able to examine 1000 rows of information without data paging, filtering (searching) or at least scrolling of the data in the web browser. So the displaying of about 50 or 100 row as maximum is what I would recommend you. Look at another [old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4374163/how-to-improve-performance-of-jqgrid/4375921#4375921) for more details and see included examples.

Comment: Thanks oleg I have used the same way you mentioned and I am able to use the functionality the way I intend to!Thanks a lot